# what's the difference between deserialization and normalization?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is to "deserialize" and "normalize" the same thing or are there differences? A straightforward question. I believe this is generic to front-end models communication to backend database sources/APIs. But if not, this is in the context of Ember Data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are differences. When you deseralize your intention is to change from one form say a javascript object and turning it into another form say a ember-data model. When you normalize your intention is to manipulate the data and/or structure of the current form.

So with ember-data you have `RESTSerializer` with:

- **serialize** which takes a model and turns it into a plain javascript object.
- **normalize** which takes a plain javascript object and returns a plain javascript object.

Compared to [transforms/date.js](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/transforms/date.js):

- **deserialize** Given a number or string returns a Date object.
- **serialize** Returns a string representation of a Date object.

To put both of these things in context, from the docs on the [applyTransforms](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/addon/serializers/json.js#L180) method on JSONSerializer (this is where the transforms work on the plain javascript object):

> Given a subclass of `DS.Model` and a JSON object this method will
>      iterate through each attribute of the `DS.Model` and invoke the
>      `DS.Transform#deserialize` method on the matching property of the
>      JSON object.  This method is typically called after the
>      serializer's `normalize` method.